# TypeScript gives warnings on access to object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on Angular 4. I was trying to loop object/array using for loop.
I am getting output in console but in the build and compile getting errors. Not sure what mistake i am doing.

my data will look like this

```
let ArrayVal =  [{
       comparator: 'EQ',
       flight: [{
           number: 123
          }, {
           grouping: 'Flight Group South America'
          }]
      }, {
       comparator: 'NEQ',
       flight: [{
           number: 7000,
           endNumber: 7999
          }]
      }];
```

now i need to fetch numbers from this above data, expected output is numbers =
 ['123','7000-7999']

so tried something like this

```
let numbers: any = [];
for ( let val of ArrayVal){
 for (let flight of val.flight) {
    if ( flight.hasOwnProperty('number') && flight.hasOwnProperty('endNumber') ) {
      numbers.push(flight.number + '-' + flight.endNumber );
    }else if  (flight.hasOwnProperty('number')) {
      numbers.push(flight.number);
    }
 }
}
console.log(numbers)
```

i am getting output as expected in console numbers = [123, "7000-7999"] but issue is getting error in build and compile

```
TS2339: Property 'endNumber' does not exist on type '{ number: number; } | { grouping: string; }'.
      Property 'endNumber' does not exist on type '{ number: number; }'.
TS2339: Property 'number' does not exist on type '{ number: number; } | { grouping: string; }'.
  Property 'number' does not exist on type '{ grouping: string; }'.
```

could someone tell me and help me to loop this data.
**flight.number** gives error property number doesnt exist on type '{ number: number; } | { grouping: string; }'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `any[]` to the declaration of ArrayVal.

This happens because `TypeScript` tries to infer the structure of the objects contained in the array, but it does it wrong as the structure is different on both `flight` arrays.

Check the following [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20data%3A%20any%5B%5D%20%3D%20%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comparator%3A%20'EQ'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flight%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'number'%3A%20123%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grouping%3A%20'Flight%20Group%20South%20America'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20comparator%3A%20'NEQ'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flight%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'number'%3A%207000%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endNumber%3A%207999%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20numbers%3A%20any%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(%20let%20val%20of%20data)%7B%0D%0A%20for%20(let%20flight%20of%20val.flight)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%20flight.hasOwnProperty('number')%20%26%26%20flight.hasOwnProperty('endNumber')%20)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numbers.push(flight.number%20%2B%20'-'%20%2B%20flight.endNumber%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7Delse%20if%20%20(flight.hasOwnProperty('number'))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20numbers.push(flight.number)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(numbers))

UPDATE:

An even cleaner approach would be to define interfaces for your data (this means actually make use of TS):

```
interface Data {
  comparator: string;
  flight: Flight[];
}

interface Flight {
  'number'?: number;
  grouping?: string;
  endNumber?: number;
}

let data: Data[] = [{
       comparator: 'EQ',
       flight: [{
           'number': 123
          }, {
           grouping: 'Flight Group South America'
          }]
      }, {
       comparator: 'NEQ',
       flight: [{
           'number': 7000,
           endNumber: 7999
          }]
      }];

let numbers: any = [];

for ( let val of data){
 for (let flight of val.flight) {
    if ( flight.hasOwnProperty('number') && flight.hasOwnProperty('endNumber') ) {
      numbers.push(flight.number + '-' + flight.endNumber );
    }else if  (flight.hasOwnProperty('number')) {
      numbers.push(flight.number);
    }
 }

}
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: This is the solution but I would not recommend adding `any` because typescript is strongly typed. We will be loosing the whole essence of typescript's functionality. This will be a dirty hack to fool the compiler

Comment: Okay now I agree with you

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
for (let flight of val.flight) {
    if ( flight.hasOwnProperty('number') && flight.hasOwnProperty('endNumber') ) {
      numbers.push(flight.number + '-' + flight.endNumber );
    }else if  (flight.hasOwnProperty('number')) {
      numbers.push(flight.number);
    }
 }
```

You could do:

```
 for (let flight of val.flight) {
    if ( flight?.number && flight?.endNumber ) {
      numbers.push(flight.number + '-' + flight.endNumber );
    } else if (flight?.number) {
      numbers.push(flight.number);
    }
 }
```

This is provided that `number` and `endNumber` are not 0 just to be sure.

Comment: this wont prevent the warnings

Comment: To my knowledge and I just tried this, there are no errors or warnings with this "existential operator". If there is a property, the sub-expression evaluates to true; if not, it evaluates to false. The `?.` operator "soaks up" null references and it's designed specifically for this type or property accessing.